# I have a Python IndexError: list index out of range error

Tags: python, index-error

#display the ski from the file

```
for row in ski_details:
    groupsTV.insert('','end', text = row[0], values= (row[1], row[2], row[3]))
```

When i comment out the for row in ski_details line and the groupsTV.insert line, i receive no error in Python shell, but no data in my table.

When i remove comments, i get the following

```
groupsTV.insert('','end', text = row[0], values= (row[1], row[2], row[3]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am looking to have data from "skigroups.txt" into a Treeview display.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take checkout at [tour], [ask] and [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Currently your question, is hard to read without the proper formatting.

Comment: In one or more cases, `row` has fewer than 4 items in it. If you use a debugger to launch your code, you will be able to see what is in `row` when the exception occurs, and thus have an idea of what the issue is.

Answer (score 2):

You must learn how to
[debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs).
The debugging task at hand is to understand what `row` contains.

```
for ...
    print(row)
    print(len(row))
    assert len(row) >= 4
    groupsTV.insert...
```

At least one of your rows has fewer than four elements.

Identify the errant row, and arrange for it
to contain the necessary elements.
Or simply skip it:

```
for ...
    if len(row) < 4:
        continue
    groupsTV.insert...
```